# How to create a file upload field in a form in Pardot?

Tags: custom-field, fields, form, pardot

I've created some forms in Pardot and I need to add a file upload field to one of them but I don't know how. I couldn't find such field type in custom fields as well 
I attached an image to explain what I want to create.can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using pardot forms this isn't currently possible. I'd suggest creating your own form or use a 3rd party form and post the data to pardot using a form handler

You'd need to store the file upload within a separate location as pardot wouldn't be able to host the file from a form submission